# how can i use html5 UI in android user interface instead of widget?(without phonegap)

Tags: android

iam a newbie in android development .

i want to display my own css styled html5 inside toast, dialog popup.(without phonegap)

is there a way i can store html pages inside project folder and put it inside UI ?

Is webview only for loading webpages from external server?

Comment: You can always take a look at what is available in the [`android.webkit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html) package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Display own styled html5 in a webview**

```
String myView = "<html><body>Smothing <b>Awesome</b>.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(myView, "text/html", null);
```

**Display inside toast, dialog popup**

Reference the code in your popups, might not work in toast (do experiment), instead you can custom your toast by creating your own xml file and referencing it in your toast

**Store html pages inside project**

Use cache, you can store all pages which will be pushed to your UI/WebViews by default

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html

**webview only for loading webpages from external server**

No as above display own styled html5 views in a webview